# Custom Event from Item Renderer not detected by a class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, itemrenderer, custom-event

I am trying to dispatch a custom event from an item renderer(which is a child of the Main application file / root).

Code in Main.mxml:

```
<s:List id="movieGrid"itemRenderer="views.MovieRenderer" dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection()}">
    </s:List>

<s:Group width="100%" height="100%" bottom="60">
            <views:DetailedViewInfo id="detailed" includeIn="MoviePage" />
    </s:Group>
```

Renderer (something clicked):

```
MyEventDispatcher.Dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new MovieClickEvent(MovieClickEvent.CLICKED, data));
```

DetailedViewInfo (creation complete):

```
MyEventDispatcher.Dispatcher.addEventListener(MovieClickEvent.CLICKED, clickHandler);
```

MyEventDispatcher:

```
package events
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    public class MyEventDispatcher
    {   
        public static var Dispatcher:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    }
}
```

Event:

```
package events
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MovieClickEvent extends Event
    {
        public function MovieClickEvent(type:String, theMovieData:Object, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            this._result = theMovieData;
        }

        public function get result():Object
        {
            return this._result;
        }

        override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new MovieClickEvent(type, result, bubbles, cancelable)
        }

        public static const CLICKED:String = "MovieClickEvent.CLICKED";

        private var _result:Object;

    }
}
```

I am able to listen for the event successfully in the Main.mxml but I also need to detect it in a SkinnableContainer - "DetailedViewInfo" that is also a child of Main.mxml:

It his possible at all? I tried importing all related events / classes and same for declarations. It does not work even if I comment out the event listener in Main.mxml. I tried adding a declaration to the item renderer in DetailedViewInfo but that crashes the application with no understandable error.

Could someone explain to me how this should be done? I am using custom events all over the place in my application and hadn't had this happen before. Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: You didn't provide us w/ the event class.  Since you have a custom constructor for MovieClickEvent it is impossible to tell what you've set the bubbling property to.  If the bubble is set to false (the default value), then the parent of the List class will never receive the event.  You must set Bubble to true in order for the List's parent to receive events dispatched from the itemRenderer.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com He's not dispatching from the ItemRenderer, he's dispatching from a static `EventDispatcher` instance that is not on the displaylist. Hence the event will not bubble either way.

Comment: Question edited to include event code, I also tried both with bubbles true and false.

Comment: @RIAstar I did not catch that; so good catch.  I guess I didn't review code close enough, instead referring to review the question text which tells a different picture.

Comment: So I take it that it is not possible? If so what is a good alternative(s)?

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't be possible. But I can't tell what's going wrong. Unless you would be adding the event listener _after_ the event was dispatched. I see you have an `includeIn` statement there: this means that component will not be immediately created, but only when the `MoviePage` state is entered. The event may be dispatched _before_ the component is created and the event listener attached. That said, I'm not a huge fan of the static EventDispatcher approach (I've tried it) and I would propagate events through bubbling as @www.Flextras.com suggests.

Comment: Actually that could be it! Very astute observation, will try it and report back. I'm still quite green when it comes to programming, could you give me an idea of a better approach to events? I mean how could I make use of bubbling in this case(since it is dispatched from a class)?

Comment: I tried without "MyEventDispatcher" and unfortunately I hit identical issue. With bubbles = false I get nothing at all, event listener with bubbles = true I get event in Main.mxml. Is there anything else abvious I could be missing? Or maybe I absolutely must re-dispatch the event in this case, if so a link to some more info about that would be great...

Comment: Any ideas at all? Cant get it to work at all... Also @RIAstar please add an answer as the comment did answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem you're adding the event listener *after* the event was dispatched. I see you have an `includeIn` statement there: this means the `DetailedViewInfo` component will not be immediately created, but only when the `MoviePage` state is entered. The event may be dispatched before the component is created and the event listener attached.

The quick fix for this issue, is to not use `includeIn`, but set the component's visibility according to the current state:

```
<views:DetailedViewInfo id="detailed" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"
    visible.MoviePage="true" includeInLayout.MoviePage="true" />
```

However, you may want to review your architecture if you need to resort to this. Unfortunately I can't tell you much more than that, since I don't know your current architecture.

Comment: Currently I am getting ~15 values from local sql database and passing it to list / itemRenderer (renderer only uses 3 values) which when clicked passes data to the DetailedViewComponent. Thinking about it now seems foolish though, performance or bandwidth is not an issue locally so I guess I didn't think much about it. Will just get the data for my DetailedViewInfo component directly from sqlLite db from now on, Thanks!